# How to add someone as a developer to a discord bot

Tags: discord

**NOTE: I don't need any coding support.**

I was making a Discord bot and my friend wanted to join but I am not sure how to add him as a developer. I want to add him as a developer in https://discord.com/developers so when the bot gets verified we both get the badge.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: @Jawad yes he can

Comment: @Zer0 I stand corrected

Comment: In future, can you please not spam tags that aren't related to your question. This only needed the `discord` with only the possible inclusion of `discord.py` as that's the lib you use.

Answer (score 4):

Put the bot into a team, click Teams on the left side of the [Discord Developer Page](https://discord.com/developers)
or click [here](https://discord.com/developers/teams). Click 'New Team', give it a name then invite team member, invite your friend. Then you wanna go to your bots [application page](https://discord.com/developers/applications), scroll down a little if you need to and click 'Transfer App to Team' select your team with your friend in and if necessary enter your 2fa code.

Comment: It does not allow me to add my bot to the team i made, i selected the name of my team nd entered the 2FA code, still it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a team is what fits you best, you can find all information about to create one, add users etc [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/teams)